# If a function is discontinuous at one point, then filled in, is it now continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I am looking at the continuity of the following function $f(x) = \sin(1/|x|), f(0) = 0$

So this is $f(x) = \sin(1/|x|)$ filled in at $x = 0$

Clearly, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0 $ by squeeze theorem.

Is $f(x)$ continuous then?

In general, when is a function that is filled in continuous or discontinuous?

Comment: Actually the limit as $x\to0$ does not exist for this function.

Comment: It is not true that $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(1/|x|) = 0$ because the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: It's not continuous at $x=0$ because the limit does not exist there.

Comment: A function does not become continuous if it is defined at an additional point in general.

Comment: Maybe you mean $f(x) = \sin(1/|x|)|x|, f(0) = 0$ or something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is no.  The function is not continuous at $x=0$ because $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$ does not exist.

The easiest way to see that is to notice that it oscillates between $-1$ and $+1$ infinitely often in every interval $(0,\epsilon)$ so it cannot be approaching any fixed value.

Answer (score 7):

In general, if $f(a)$ is not defined for some point $a$, but
$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L$
for some value $L$, then we have a *redefinable discontinuity*.  Intuitively, that means that the graph has a hole in it, but the hole can be plugged by simply extending the function to a new function defined on a larger domain by:
$$\hat{f}(x) = \begin{cases} 
f(x) & x \ne a \\
L & x=a
\end{cases}$$

This new function $\hat{f}(x)$ is continuous at $a$, because $$\lim_{x\to a}\hat{f}(x) = \lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L = \hat{f}(a)$$.

In the particular example of $f(x)=\sin(1/|x|)$, though, this method does not work, because the limit does not exist in the first place.

Comment: Oh....I misapplied squeeze theorem cause $\sin(1/|x|)$ reminded me of $\sin(x)/x$. So in this case we drive $x$ to $0$, however $1/|x|$ approaches infinity, so $\sin(1/|x|)$ will keep on oscillating

Comment: Note that $\sin(x)/x$ *also* does not go to $0$ -- on the contrary, its limit as $x\to 0$ is $1$. However, if the function were $f(x)=x\sin(1/|x|)$ then as $x\to 0$ the oscillations are damped down and we do in fact have $f(x)\to 0$ by the squeeze theorem.